# verify thenull hypothesis for a random sample of IID random variables distribuited as a uniform

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

Let $(X_1, \dots , X_n)$ be a random sample of i.i.d. random variables distributed
as uniform $U[0,\theta]$

1. Verify null hypothesis $H_{0} :\theta = \theta_{0}$ versus $H_{1} :\theta \not=\theta_{0}$ through likelihood ratio test, with level of signicance fixed equal to $\alpha$
2. Verify null hypothesis $H_{0} : \theta = 7$ versus $H_1: \theta = 8$ considering a test
   with the following rejection region:
   $R = ({(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_6) : 
   max(X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4, X_5, X_6) = X_{(6)}  > 6})$

I have calculated as $\alpha = P(X_{(n)} > 6|\theta = 7) = 1- \left(\frac{6}{7}\right)^{6}$ = $0.6034$

and $\beta = P(X_{(n)} < 6|\theta = 8) = \left(\frac{6}{8}\right)^{6} = 0.178$

From here how can I verify the null hypothesis? Thanks in advance

Comment: Usual notations for the max of six iid RVs $X_i$ are $X_{(6)}$ and $X_{6:6}.$ Apparently, you are using the first. Fixed your JAX code to show that. // Your significance level is too large to be useful in practice. // It is not clear what you're asking. Do you want verification of your probabilities $\alpha, \beta,$ which seem OK? Do you want to see an example? How did you decide on 6 as the critical value?

Comment: so once i calculate $\alpha$ and $\beta$ I am done with this exercise is there no need  to check anything else?

Comment: maybe an example might clarify